# Повторный вывод на страницу

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$get_names = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `users`");

// ВЫВОДИМ СПИСОК ИМЁН

while($name = mysql_fetch_row($get_names)) {
    if(isset($name[0])) {
        echo $name[0]."<br>"; // выводит имена пользователей
    }
}

// ВЫВОДИМ СПИСОК ИМЁН ЕЩЁ РАЗ

while($name = mysql_fetch_row($get_names)) {
    if(isset($name[0])) {
        echo $name[0]."<br>"; // здесь ничего не выводится..
    }
}
```

Почему не выводятся данные во втором цикле?

Comment: Ну так вы все записи вывели, больше их нет, а `mysql_fetch_row` как раз и получает только следующую запись, а не прошлые. Чтобы сбросить указатель записей в вашем случае надо использовать [mysql_data_seek](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-data-seek.php). Тогда вы опять будете в начале списка и сможете использовать `mysql_fetch_row` повторно

Comment: Да, я так и полагал, что дело именно во внутреннем указателе. Благодарю.

Comment: Расширение `mysql_` устарело, от него надо избавляться (как минимум заменить на `mysqli`). Да и подход с перемоткой результатов сомнительный. Лучше получить набор записей, а потом использовать уже его

Comment: @stashappy, функции `mysql_*` ***УСТАРЕЛИ!!!*** Используйте как минимум `mysqli_*` функции.

Comment: Приятель, я понял, понял. Зачем же так громко...

Answer (score 1):

потому что вы все уже fetch сделали и больше нету данных из курсора

попробуйте так

```
$get_names = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `users`");

// ВЫВОДИМ СПИСОК ИМЁН
$k=0;
while($name[$k] = mysql_fetch_row($get_names)) {
    if(isset($name[$k][0])) {
        echo $name[$k][0]."<br>"; // выводит имена пользователей
    }
    $k++;
}

// ВЫВОДИМ СПИСОК ИМЁН ЕЩЁ РАЗ
$k=0;
while(isset($name[$k])) {
    if(isset($name[$k][0])) {
        echo $name[$k][0]."<br>"; // здесь ничего не выводится..
    }
    $k++;
}
```

есть еще другие методы, но написал самый не меняюший ваш код